# Base Class Pointer pointing to a Derived Class Object which is a template variable in another class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, template-classes

Sorry if the title is not clear.But, I'll try to explain the problem clearly.

---

I am working on a **c++** and **QT** using **MVC** for the application architecture:

[image]

**- Some description for application structure:**

- **Model Section (designed using polymorphism pattern):**

  is responsible for database related stuff, It has an *IDataBase.h* interface and its implementation for sqlite database type.
      **IDataBase.h :**

  ```
  namespace model{
     class IDataBase;
  }
  class IDataBase
  {
  public:
      virtual ~IDataBase(){
          //;
      }

      virtual bool connect(const QString &db) = 0;

      virtual bool insertData(QMap<QString,QVariant> &queryData, const 
      QString &table) = 0;
  };
  ```

  **sqlitedb.h**

  ```
  class SqliteDB: public IDataBase
  {
  public:
      SqliteDB();
      ~SqliteDB();
      bool connect(const QString &db)    
      bool insertData(QMap<QString,QVariant> &queryData, const QString &table);
  private:
      QSqlDatabase m_database;
  };
  ```
- **Controller Section**: I am using the template class ***DataBaseService*** to manage any type of databases (mysql, sqlite ....).

  **DataBaseService.h**
  // template variable is the database type class

  ```
  template<class T> 
  class DatabaseService
  {
  public:
      DatabaseService();
      ~DatabaseService();
      bool addProduct(QMap<QString,QVariant> &queryData, const QString &table);
  private:
       std::unique_ptr<IDataBase> m_database;
  };
  ```

  ***DataBaseService.cpp***

  ```
  template<class T>
  DatabaseService<T>::DatabaseService()
  {
      m_database = std::make_unique<T>();
      m_database->connect("db.sqlite");    
  }
  ```

**- The Problem is :**

When I try to create a pointer of class **DatabaseService** with the template variable **SqliteDB** in ***main.cpp*** file :

```
 DatabaseService<model::SqliteDB> *sqliteDb = new DatabaseService<model::SqliteDB>();
```

***I get This unresolved externals error :***

> error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl
>   DatabaseService::DatabaseService(void)"
>   (??0?$DatabaseService@VSqliteDB@model@@@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in
>   function main

**- My Questions :**

> 1. what is wrong in my design?
> 2. Is there any better way to design the database workflow?

---

**- Edit:**
                                                              After I Read the links that are provided by  **Miles Budnek** I understood how templates actually works and I know that I have three options to write template class implementation :

1. Write implementation directly in header file.
2. write implementation in .cpp file an write  explicit instantiations in cpp file.
3. Write implementation in .tpp file and include it at the end of header file.

So, I used the second method and wrote *explicit instantiation* for using model::SqliteDB class: at the end of ***DataBaseService.cpp***

```
    template class DatabaseService<model::SqliteDB>;
```

This solved the unresolved externals error!
But now I have another error when trying to create an **IDatabase** pointer for **SQliteDB** object in DataBaseService.cpp in the line:

```
 m_database = std::make_unique<T>();
```

Errors :

> error: no viable overloaded '='
>
> error: C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'std::unique_ptr>' (or
>   there is no acceptable conversion) with [
>       T=model::SqliteDB,
>       _Ty=model::SqliteDB ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Thanks, i will read this and try to find the problem!.

Comment: Another related question, maybe a better dup: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: I will read this also,however if  you have time just give me your opinion about the design of model and controller sections, please!

Comment: It seems like a reasonable design.  If you want a full review I would recommend you post a question over on [codereview.se] once you have everything working.  You may want to look into an off-the-shelf ORM or data access library though, if your usage is at all complicated.  They'll likely have spent a lot more time and effort than you can to make sure things are free of bugs and security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I solved the unresolved externals error thanks to your links. But, I have encountered another error.I edited my question with details @Miles Budnek.